# Custom Field Names Using Symfony Forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to figure out how I can use more custom form field names using Symfony's form builder functionality while still being able to use components like the `Validator` and CSRF protection.

For example, Symfony automatically sets field names to the format `form_name[form_field]`, while I want to set it as something like `form_name[$var1][labels][$var2]`.

This is very easy to do using plain HTML forms but I haven't found a simple way to do it using the form builder.

This is what I have right now:

```
// ...

foreach($session->get("agreement_form_data")->areasOfWork as $area) {
    foreach($this->get("service.label_manager")->getLabelsByArea($area) as $label) {
        $form->add(StringFunctions::toHtmlId($label->getLabelName()), TextType::class, [
            "constraints" => [
                new Assert\NotBlank()
            ]
        ]);
    }
    $form->add("create_agreement", SubmitType::class, [
        "label" => "Create Agreement"
    ]);
}

// ...

return $this->render("create-agreement.html.twig", [
    "form" => $form->createView()
]);
```

HTML/Twig:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block page_title %}Create Agreement - Page 2{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

How would I return the form values as a more complex array?

Comment: For all practical purposes you can't.  The forms components uses the name to map data back into your objects when the form is posted.  You might dig down to see where this mapping is implemented but the forms component code is pretty opaque.  If you really really really need to do this then don't use the form component.

Comment: I understand, but I'm not mapping the fields on the form to an underlying class. I'm creating the fields based on varying values from a database. I was just hoping to easily take advantage of the `Validation` component without using an entity. I may have to just use a separate validation bundle to use with plain HTML form data. I need to send a variety of information attached to each field, which is why I need this solution.